# Restrict the usage of USB device to specific application

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, usb

Is it possible to restrict the usage of a USB device to a specific application?
At the moment every application can implement a specific SDK and use the USB device.

Answer (score 1):

in windows this is called `exclusive access` or `exclusive mode`. windows uses this frequently for keyboards and other HID devices for security reasons (shall prvent keyloggers from hooking...)

this also exists in linux. it can be invoked by using `TIOCEXCL` option of `ioctl`

`ioctl(fd,TIOCEXCL)`

root has always access ...

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/691676/getting-exclusive-access-to-a-tty-device-from-a-root-program-on-linux

http://lklm.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0506.1/0384.html

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/39848203/difference-between-o-cloexec-and-tiocexcl